# Натуральная сортировка массива объектов по нескольким условиям

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Имеем массив объектов:

```
const data = [
            {"name": "John", "email": "john3@mail.com", "age": 36},
            {"name": "Alex", "email": "john11@mail.com", "age": 18},
            {"name": "Mari", "email": "john31@mail.com", "age": 18},
            {"name": "John", "email": "john201@mail.com", "age": 19},
            {"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com", "age": 25},
        ];
```

Массив условия для сортировки может состоять из разного количества элементов и в разной последовательности:

```
const condition = { "sort_by": [ "name", "age"]};
```

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая выполнит эту сортировку,
причем при применение данных 2 условий мы сначала должны отсортировать
по ключу name, а потом отсортированный массив еще отсортировать по ключу
age, не теряя результата первой сортировки, т.е. после первого прохода
получаем вот такой массив (сортировка по name):

```
 [
      { name: 'Alex', email: 'john11@mail.com', age: 18 },
      { name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@mail.com', age: 25 },
      { name: 'John', email: 'john3@mail.com', age: 36 },
      { name: 'John', email: 'john201@mail.com', age: 19 },
      { name: 'Mari', email: 'john31@mail.com', age: 18 }
    ]
```

конечный результат должен быть вот таким:

```
[
      { name: 'Alex', email: 'john11@mail.com', age: 18 },
      { name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@mail.com', age: 25 },
      { name: 'John', email: 'john3@mail.com', age: 19 },
      { name: 'John', email: 'john201@mail.com', age: 36 },
      { name: 'Mari', email: 'john31@mail.com', age: 18 }
    ]
```

Мы меняем только 2 записи местами, 2-х John по возрасту, но остальная сортировка не меняется.
Написал вот такой код:

```
const sortBy = (cond, arr) => {
    const keys = cond.sort_by;
    const inputArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))
    let sortedArray;
    keys.forEach(key => {
        sortedArray = inputArr.sort((a, b) => {
            return (typeof (a[key]) === 'number'  && typeof (b[key]) === 'number')
                     ? a[key] - b[key] : a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
        })
    })
    return sortedArray
}
```

Но такой код делает сортировку 2 раза (сначала сортирует по name, а потом этот же массив
сортирует по age и результат первой сортировки пропадает), и я получаю не тот результат что мне нужен. Подскажите как исправить эту проблему?

Если использовать такие условия сортировки:

```
sortedArray = inputArr.sort((a, b) => (a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.age - b.age))
```

то все работает как нужно, за исключением того, что я указываю хардкором ключи по которым сортирую, а они могут быть разные))

```js
const data = [
                {"name": "John", "email": "john3@mail.com", "age": 36},
                {"name": "Alex", "email": "john11@mail.com", "age": 18},
                {"name": "Mari", "email": "john31@mail.com", "age": 18},
                {"name": "John", "email": "john201@mail.com", "age": 19},
                {"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com", "age": 25},
            ];
            
const condition = { "sort_by": [ "name", "age"]};

const sortBy = (cond, arr) => {

    const keys = cond.sort_by;
    const inputArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))
    let sortedArray;
    keys.forEach(key => {

        //sortedArray = inputArr.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]) || a[key] - b[key] )

        //sortedArray = inputArr.sort((a, b) => (a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.age - b.age))
        sortedArray = inputArr.sort((a, b) => {
            //console.log(typeof (a[key]) === 'number' && typeof (b[key]) === 'number')
            return (typeof (a[key]) === 'number'  && typeof (b[key]) === 'number') ? a[key] - b[key] : a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
        })
    })
    return sortedArray
}
console.log(sortBy(condition, data))
```

Comment: Исправил входные данные, "age" имеет тип number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```js
const data = [
  {"name": "John", "email": "john3@mail.com", "age": 36},
  {"name": "Alex", "email": "john11@mail.com", "age": 18},
  {"name": "Mari", "email": "john31@mail.com", "age": 18},
  {"name": "John", "email": "john201@mail.com", "age": 19},
  {"name": "Jane", "email": "jane@mail.com", "age": 25},
];

const compare = (a, b) => {
  if (a === b) return 0;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
}

const sortBy = (fields, arr) => {

  return arr.sort((a, b) => {
    for (field of fields) {          
      const result = compare(a[field], b[field]);
      
      if (result === 0) continue;
      
      return result;
    }
    
    return 0;
  })
}

console.log(sortBy(["name", "age"], data));
console.log('---------------------------------------------------------')
console.log(sortBy(["name"], data));
console.log('---------------------------------------------------------')
console.log(sortBy(["email"], data));
```

Comment: Нет это не подходит, в условии может быть "name" и  "emai" или только  "email"

Comment: @Alex Не понял, `sort_by` может быть не массивом имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Alex Добавил ещё выходных данных, скажите пожалуйста, что в выводах не правильно?

Comment: sort_by будет всегда массивом, но он может содержать не только "name" и "age", это может быть ["email", "name"] или ["email"]

Comment: @Alex Обновил алгоритм, проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: алгоритм работает верно в 2-х первых вариантах, а вот с сортировкой по "email" нет, 
элемент с "email": `john11@mail.com` должен стоять первым, `'jane@mail.com'` вторым.
Я думаю это из-за того, что `sort()` с таким compare работает хорошо со строками без чисел и с числами, а вот стоки которые состоят из символом и чисел, как email, сравнивает не корректно, поэтому я в своем коде использовал `localeCompare()`

Comment: @Alex Я извиняюсь, но почему `john11@mail.ru` должен стоять первым, если у `jane@mail.com`, вторая буква `a`, что по порядку выше чем `o`?

Comment: @Alex Решение рабочее. `localeCompare()` также поставит `jane@mail.com` на первое место. Да и другой результат сложно себе представить.

Comment: @EzioMercer Согласен с вами, решение рабочее, я за основу взял то как сравнивает `localeCompare()`, но проверил в консоли и убедился. Спасибо Вам за помощь. Хотел бы еще уточнить для чего мы после цикла  возвращаем `return 0`?

Comment: @Alex Обращайтесь! Делаем этот `return 0`, чтобы вернуть 0 для тех двух элементов, у которых все поля будут одинаковыми, ведь в самом цикле если значения полей одинаковые то итерация пропускается и мы не попадаем на строку `return result`, а значит если все будут одинаковыми то мы никогда не попадём на эту строку в цикле. А если значения всех полей одинаковые - значит оба элемента одинаковые, потому верным решением будет возвращать 0, иначе вернётся `undefined`, а я не знаю к чему это приведёт (может быть даже будет интерпретироваться как 0) не охота было разбираться)